# Defference between where(IN(' ')) and Wher(IN(' '))

Tags: mysql

What is difference between `WHERE (uID IN('2,3'))` and `WHERE (uID IN(2,3))`

Answer (score 2):

The first one is only true if `uID` equals the text literal `2,3`. The second is true if `uID` is numerically either `2` or `3`.